# Telerik RadFile Explorer change icon of folder

Tags: telerik

In telerik radfile explorer, I want to change icon of the folder.
How can I do that? They are providing webresouce.axd file and in that they are having different icons for different stuff. 
If I change and overwrite it, In zoom level it is not showing in good quality.
How Can i put brand new icon which is designed by me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a lot on internet, I was helpless. Then I got idea to do something innovative.
What I've done is through css & javascript.css you have to add at the last. ( I know it's not well structured, but that's the only way you can stop telerik to override your css. If you add in start of head tag, telerik will override it)

So, here's the css you can change.
.rfeThumbnailView .rfeFile .rfeFileIcon
    {
        background-image: url('')!important;
    }

```
.RadFileExplorer .rfeThumbList .folder
{
    background-position: -38px 0px!important;
}
```

And you gotta add this javascript function
function changespan() {

```
        var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span.rfeFileIcon');

        var j = spans.length;
        var k = 0;
        for (var i = j - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            var a = document.createElement('img');
            a.src = "folder.png";

            //alert(spans[i].childElementCount);
            if (spans[i].childElementCount > 0) {
            }
            else {
                spans[i].appendChild(a);//.appendChild(a.previousSibling);}
            }

        }
    }
```

And call this function on each and every event of telerik RadFileExplorer that causes change.
Here are few events that I'm using.

OnClientItemSelected

OnClientFileOpen

OnClientFolderChange

OnClientInit

OnClientLoad

OnClientFolderLoaded

OnClientFilter

Hope this will help someone. If you have any questions, then you can always ask me!